Recommendations for a jQuery or Bootstrap color picker with custom palette management
I'm looking for a jQuery color picker that allows users to create and manage their own palette of preset colors. Specifically, I need the following features:

Users should be able to create and save custom colors to a palette.
The color picker should remember these custom colors even after the page is refreshed.
Users should be able to delete any custom colors they have created.

Does anyone have recommendations for a jQuery or Bootstrap plugin that meets these requirements? Thank you!
